# how to add a cookie in response object

Tags: java

My code is REST style and there is a function returned with:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(responseMessage);
```

I want to know how to add a cookie in the response? I tried `HttpServletResponse` object to add a cookie but failed.

Comment: Can you specify what have you tried so far?

Comment: @henriqueromao the param of the function contains HttpServletResponse object named response, and I add a cookie into this. but the client can not get this cookie

Comment: @henriqueromao could I just add the cookie in ResponseEntity? thanks

Comment: How are you receiving the cookie in the client?

Comment: @henriqueromao I check with chrome but did not find this cookie

Comment: Check out here, see if it helps you: [CookieTuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0k1d5BlXR0)

Comment: @henriqueromao thanks a lot